# js files occasionally failing to load

Tags: php, apache-2.4, php-fpm, javascript

We have a newly configured php7 16cpu 32gb RAM Linux server.
Plenty of power for what we need.

We have a basic form on a page that requires a login.

However, sometimes when a user lands on the page, the js files fail to load which in turn prevents them from logging in.

This doesn’t happen every time, but often enough to where we cannot use the newly configured server.

KeepAlive is enabled, as seen by this curl command:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Content-Length: 0 Connection: keep-alive
```

I have attached an image of what we’re seeing.

Could this have anything to do with server/Apache configuration, as we notice the js files always fail at the 10 second mark.

Btw,

[js errors timing out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PqW0.jpg)

[drilldown into one of the js errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIQQN.png)

Comment: What does the details window show when you select one of the "Failed" lines?

Comment: Not necessarily an Apache problem.  Firewall?  Server losing connection to the internet.  Router?

Comment: Gerard - this only happens on the new server. ie if we swap it out for the old one in the load balancer everything works fine. Tero - let me see if i can get that

Comment: @TeroKilkanen - i have attached an image of one of the failed lines.

Comment: So, the load is being balanced? Between this new server and ... ?

Comment: Check if load balancer has any logs and what they show.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille between this new server and the old server. ie we're trying to replace the old server with the new one. But the new server occasionally gets the js load error issues so we have to remove it for now.